# Is CUDA pinned memory zero-copy?

Tags: cuda

Pinned memory is supposed to increase transfer rates from host to device ([api](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad.html#g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad) reference).  However I found that I do not need to call cuMemcpyHtoD for the kernel to access the values, or cuMemcpyDtoA for the host to read the values back.  I didn't think this would work, but it does:

```
__global__ void testPinnedMemory(double * mem)
{
    double currentValue = mem[threadIdx.x];
    printf("Thread id: %d, memory content: %f\n", threadIdx.x, currentValue);
    mem[threadIdx.x] = currentValue+10;
}

void test() 
{
    const size_t THREADS = 8;
    double * pinnedHostPtr;
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&pinnedHostPtr, THREADS, cudaHostAllocDefault);

    //set memory values
    for (size_t i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
        pinnedHostPtr[i] = i;

    //call kernel
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(THREADS);
    dim3 numBlocks(1);
    testPinnedMemory<<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pinnedHostPtr);

    //read output
    printf("Data after kernel execution: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i)
        printf("%f ", pinnedHostPtr[i]);    
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Data after kernel execution: 10.000000 11.000000 12.000000 13.000000 14.000000 15.000000 16.000000 17.000000
Thread id: 0, memory content: 0.000000
Thread id: 1, memory content: 1.000000
Thread id: 2, memory content: 2.000000
Thread id: 3, memory content: 3.000000
Thread id: 4, memory content: 4.000000
Thread id: 5, memory content: 5.000000
Thread id: 6, memory content: 6.000000
Thread id: 7, memory content: 7.000000
```

My questions are:

- Is pinned memory zero-copy?  I thought only mapped pinned memory was zero-copy.
- If it is zero-copy why have an explicit way to map it to device ([cudaHostAlloc](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html) with cudaHostAllocMapped option)

I'm using CUDA Toolkit 5.5, Quadro 4000 with driver set to TCC mode, and compilation options sm_20,compute_20

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Congratulations! You're encountering a 2.x compute capability + TCC + 64-bit OS feature with newer CUDA versions :)

Read the rest to find out more!

First a small theory summary as CUDA taught us:

- **Pinned memory** is not zero-copy since the GPU cannot access it (it's not mapped in its address space) and it's used to efficiently transfer from the host to the GPU. It's page-locked (valuable kernel resource) memory and has some performance advantages over pageable normal memory.
- **Pinned zero-copy memory** is page-locked memory (usually allocated with the `cudaHostAllocMapped` flag) which is also used by the GPU since mapped to its address space.

Why you're accessing memory allocated from the host from the device without explicitly specifying it?

Take a look at the release notes for CUDA 4.0 (and higher):

> - (Windows and Linux) Added support for unified virtual address space.
>
> Devices supporting 64-bit and compute 2.0 and higher capability now
>   share a single unified address space between the host and all devices.
>   This means that the pointer used to access memory on the host is the
>   same as the pointer to used to access memory on the device. Therefore,
>   the location of memory may be queried directly from its pointer value;
>   the direction of a memory copy need not be specified.

To summarize: **if your card is 2.0+ (and it is: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), you are running a 64-bit OS and on Windows you have a TCC mode on, you're automatically using UVA** ([Unified Virtual Addressing](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED)) **between host and device**. That means: automatically enhancing your code with zero-copy-like accesses.

This is also in the [CUDA documentation for the current version](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) in the paragraph *"Automatic Mapping of Host Allocated Host Memory"*

Answer (score 6):

Mapped memory is a type of pinned memory.  It is created when you pin the memory and pass the `cudaHostAllocMapped` flag.  *However*, even though you've specified `cudaHostAllocDefault`, the memory is also "Mapped" under certain circumstances.  I believe TCC mode combined with a 64-bit OS is sufficient to meet the circumstances required for the "auto-Mapped" feature.

The central issue is whether [UVA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) is in effect.  In your case, it is.

Regarding the question about why having the explicit capability, it is for use in cases where UVA is not in effect (for example in a 32-bit host OS).

from the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDART__UNIFIED) (when UVA is in effect):

> Automatic Mapping of Host Allocated Host Memory
>
> All host memory allocated through all devices using cudaMallocHost()
>   and cudaHostAlloc() is always directly accessible from all devices
>   that support unified addressing. This is the case regardless of
>   whether or not the flags cudaHostAllocPortable and cudaHostAllocMapped
>   are specified.   The pointer value through which allocated host memory
>   may be accessed in kernels on all devices that support unified
>   addressing is the same as the pointer value through which that memory
>   is accessed on the host. It is not necessary to call
>   cudaHostGetDevicePointer() to get the device pointer for these
>   allocations.