# Is it possible to use GPU just for calculations without copying the variables to GPU. Can we use RAM or even HardDisk for variable stoorage?

Tags: memory, cuda

Is it possible to run operations, say like c=a+b, without copying the variables to GPU.
Say, take reference from host memory without memcopy to device.
For GPU with low memory, that would be ideal to use host memory// or maybe even hard disk.
Is there any way to do so|

Comment: As of cuda 6.0 pinned memory is no longer the only option. This should not be marked as a duplicate question due to the release of unified memory in Cuda 6.

Comment: Unified memory still copies the data to the GPU.  The question explicitly states "without copying the variables to GPU."  For a GPU with low memory, unified memory cannot help.  Pinned memory can.

Comment: but again, i ran some tests and pinned memory did not support any more variables.

Comment: I think your tests are likely flawed, in some way, then.  You might want to post a question if you are having trouble using pinned memory, and describe those tests. This question is about whether it is possible.  Yes it is possible.  And unified memory *will not* allow you to use more memory than what is on-board on your GPU (unlike pinned memory, your tests notwithstanding). You may also be interested in the [simple zero-copy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplezerocopy) cuda sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969534/cuda-pinned-memory-zero-copy-problems The code I tested was a simple modified version of this. I used structures to see how much change is observed in supported number of those structures. and the result was quiet the same. I have 8 GB ram and 1 GB GPU, So i expected different results.