# CUDA Fastest way to scatter a host 2D array to GPU

Tags: c++, cuda

The goal is to scatter a 2D array on host to a GPU array by certain indices (i.e. `arr_d[indices[i]] = arr_h[i]`). The size of `arr_h` can be up to 10000x1000, and all rows will be copied to GPU. I'd like to know the fastest way to do it.

My current solution is to pin `arr_h` and launch a kernel to do the copy work:

```cpp
__global__ void Scatter(
    int* dst, const int* src, const int* indices,
    const int len, const int lenRow) {
  constexpr int warpSize = 32;  
  const int numWarps = (blockDim.x * gridDim.x) >> 5;
  int warpId = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) >> 5;
  int laneId = threadIdx.x & 31;

  while (warpId < len) {  // Each warp copies one row
    int row = indices[warpId];
    // Each thread in the warp reads one column
    for (int col = laneId; col < lenRow; col += warpSize) {
      dst[row * lenRow + col] = src[warpId * lenRow + col];
    }
    warpId += numWarps;
  }
}
```

Since the src array is on host, I think the kernel would have many small data transfers between host and device. Is it a better idea to copy the whole `arr_h` array to the device memory first? And if so, how to perform array scattering on device in a parallelized way?

Comment: Ah, I see. In the end you will need to benchmark the different approaches on the target machine. The fastest approach might depend on the memory bandwidth of the GPU and also of the CPU. Are you sure speed is the only priority? E.g. could it be helpful to only ever have one 10000x1000 buffer in device memory s.t. the code will work on GPUs with less VRAM?

Comment: For ideal performance of the above kernel I would recommend adding padding to the rows to align them for ideal coalescing. The CUDA Runtime has some special allocation functions to help with that, like [`cudaMalloc3D()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g188300e599ded65c925e79eab2a57347).

Comment: CUB has recently aquired a feature that might be of interest here: [`cub::DeviceCopy::Batched`](https://nvidia.github.io/cccl/cub/api/structcub_1_1DeviceCopy.html#structcub_1_1devicecopy).

Comment: Have you measured the performance difference of your kernel compared to regular `cudaMemcpy` without permutation? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74225179/cuda-write-directly-from-device-to-host-pinned-memory-without-sacrificing-throu) suggests that you may already get pretty close to optimal. As far as your kernel is concerned: If you can ensure proper alignment through padding and pitched allocations, try loading `int4` vectors instead for larger transfer sizes